# Change attributes when click button Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ecmascript-6

I have a problem when i change attributes of div child, using jquery when i click on button.
correct scenario: when i press next python the attributes of twitter button changes according to the new value of `ii`.

```js
var pro = [{
    Name: 'kinto',
    Description: 'A generic JSON document store with sharing and synchronisation capabilities. http://docs.kinto-storage.org/',
    Link: 'https://github.com/Kinto/kinto',
    Language: 'python'
  },
  {
    Name: 'catapult',
    Description: 'Catapult home for performance tools.',
    Link: 'https://github.com/catapult-project/catapult',
    Language: 'python'
  }
];

function next(lang) {
  ii = Math.floor(Math.random() * (pro.length - 0) + 0);
  $(`.name`).html(`${pro[ii].Name}`);
  $(`.${lang}box`).remove(`.twitter${lang}`);
  $(`.${lang}box`).append(`<div class="twitter${lang}">
    <a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/share" data-text="Check this project" data-url="${prolist[ii].Link}" data-hashtags="counteributors" data-via="counteributors">
            Tweet
            </a>
</div>`);
}

//-------------- twitter button
window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    t = window.twttr || {};
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

  t._e = [];
  t.ready = function(f) {
    t._e.push(f);
  };

  return t;
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));

document.getElementById('shareBtn').onclick = function() {
  FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    display: 'popup',
    href: 'google.com',
  }, function(response) {});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" onclick="next('python');">next python</a>
<div class="twitterpython">
  <a id="tweetpython" class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/share" data-text="Check" data-url="" data-hashtags="c" data-via="c">
                                            Tweet
                                            </a>

</div>
```

Comment: also counteributors might mean to be countributors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to tweek your code to be:

```
$('.name').html(pro[ii].Name);
      $('.' + lang + 'box').remove('.twitter' + lang);
      $('.' + lang + 'box').append('<div class="twitter' + lang + '">
        <a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/share" data-text="Check this project" data-url="' + prolist[ii].Link + '" data-hashtags="counteributors" data-via="counteributors">
                Tweet
                </a>
    </div>`);
```

You need to access your javascript variables properly in your javascript code.  The syntax you are using seems to be intended for use in an actual html page, in html code.

Comment: Thanks for response, but i found the bug in loading twitter button.